# Trying to create a listview. Which loads as the list is scrolled down, getting the information from a PHP using volley

Tags: android, listview, scroll, refresh, pull-to-refresh

Dashboard Activity, which shows the listview

```
package renava.com.user.renava.renavamechanic;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView workList;
public ArrayList<String> customerA, progressA, addressA, dateTimeA, contactA, jobIDA, latA, lngA;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
boolean cool = false;
SimpleAdapter sampleListAdapter;
HashMap<String, String> sampleObjectMap;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sampleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    jobIDA = new ArrayList<>();
    customerA = new ArrayList<>();
    contactA = new ArrayList<>();
    addressA = new ArrayList<>();
    progressA = new ArrayList<>();
    dateTimeA = new ArrayList<>();
    latA= new ArrayList<>();
    lngA = new ArrayList<>();


    editor = getSharedPreferences("RenavaSP", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    workList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workList);

    int id;
    for (id = 1; id < 300; id++) {
        String ID = String.valueOf(id);
        jobIDA.add(ID);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL+ID;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        cool = true;

        workList.invalidateViews();

    }

    sampleListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(DashboardActivity.this, sampleArrayList, R.layout.array_orders, new String[]{
            "customerName", "progress", "address", "dateTime", "jobID"}, new int[]{R.id.nameText, R.id.progressText
            , R.id.locationText, R.id.jobIdText, R.id.timeText});

    workList.setAdapter(sampleListAdapter);

    workList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int ith, long l) {

            editor.putString("customerName", customerA.get(ith));
            editor.putString("progress", progressA.get(ith));
            editor.putString("address", addressA.get(ith));
            editor.putString("dateTime", dateTimeA.get(ith));
            editor.putString("contact", contactA.get(ith));
            editor.putString("lat", latA.get(ith));
            editor.putString("lng", lngA.get(ith));
            editor.apply();

            Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, ShowOrderActivity.class);
            DashboardActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String customerName;
    String progress;
    String address;
    String dateTime;
    String contact;
    String lat;
    String lng;

    try {
        JSONObject orderData = new JSONObject(response);

        sampleObjectMap = new HashMap<>();

        customerName = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        sampleObjectMap.put("customerName", customerName);
        customerA.add(customerName);

        progress = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_PROGRESS);
        sampleObjectMap.put("progress", progress);
        progressA.add(progress);

        address = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        sampleObjectMap.put("address", address);
        addressA.add(address);

        dateTime = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_DATE);
        sampleObjectMap.put("dateTime", dateTime);
        dateTimeA.add(dateTime);

        contact = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_CONTACT);
        sampleObjectMap.put("contact", contact);
        contactA.add(contact);

        lat = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_LAT);
        sampleObjectMap.put("lat", lat);
        latA.add(lat);

        lng = orderData.getString(Config.KEY_LNG);
        sampleObjectMap.put("lng", lng);
        lngA.add(lng);

        sampleArrayList.add(sampleObjectMap);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

XML of dashboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="renava.com.user.renava.renavamechanic.DashboardActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/workList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

array_orders file which is the array layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="customerName"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dgts__confirmation_code_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="progress"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/dgts__purple"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dgts__confirmation_code_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="address"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dgts__confirmation_code_text_size" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jobIdText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Job ID"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dgts__confirmation_code_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Date and Time"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dgts__confirmation_code_text_size" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the listview is not loading, only one item is shown.
And I think that it will also take a lot of time to load this activity if run once with 200 or more items in the list.
So, if there is any way the list is shown even if the list is not complete and then new things get added when they are downloaded from the server and automatically added to the listView too. Like facebook or any news app.
Thanks in advance

Comment: as you pass `sampleArrayList` to your adapter and size of that is 1 you see one item, you need create custom adapter to achieve your purpose

Comment: Will it also ADD items in the listView as it fetches data from the internet using the for loop? One by one?